# How to eliminate all columns with specific column name except for one particular variable/column?

Tags: python, pandas, drop

I eliminate all columns on my df that contain "OBJ" in their respective colnames with the following code:

```
d = pd.read_csv(url) 
df = d[d.columns.drop(list(d.filter(regex='OBJ')))]
```

I do want to eliminate all variables which colnames contain the character "OBJ", except for a specific variable called "REV_OBJ".

Is there a way I can eliminate all "OBJ" except for "REV_OBJ"?

Comment: not tested but try: `df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.contains("OBJ")].join(df[["REV_OBJ"]])`

Comment: or `df.filter(regex=r'(?!REV_OBJ\b)\b\w+',axis='columns')`

Comment: You also have the option of not loading them into the dataframe to start with if you never intend to use them: `df = pd.read_csv(url, usecols=lambda c: c == 'REV_OBJ' or 'OBJ' not in c)`...

Answer (score 1):

(personal preference) this is more readable:

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if not 'OBJ' in col or col=='REV_OBJ']
```

Comment: Minor note: the condition `not 'OBJ' in col` is deliberately placed as the first condition to 'short-circuit` the `OR` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension for the same, and can have one set which contains all the elements whom to remove.

```
to_remove = set([col for col in df.columns if "obj" in col.lower()]) - {'REV_OBJ'}
df.drop(to_remove, axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Comment: if there are column names with the lower case 'obj', they would be erroneously removed!

Comment: Ji Wei, I think that is not a big deal and can be handled simply. But above statements give the gist of solving a problem.